# Zend framework 3 Mysqli adapter issue

Tags: zend-framework, php-7, zend-framework3

I am trying to connect mysql to zend framework 3 application but it gives such result as below:
`Class 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli' not found`
I am using below code:

```
$config = [
            'driver'   => 'Mysqli',
            'database' => 'abc',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            // 'port'     => 27017,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
        ];
        $adapter = new Mysqli($config);
        $result = $adapter->query("select * from 
                                 table1",Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        foreach($result as $row){
            echo $row->sentence;"<br>";
        }
```

inserted this as well. `use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli;`

Comment: So, have you got the `zendframework/zend-db` module in your project? If you're starting out with ZF, grab the [Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) to help get you started. A good "book" to work through would be [Using Zend Framework 3](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/index.html). It covers all of these basics.

Comment: yes added 'Zend\Db', module. but it says ```The Mysqli extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded```

Comment: Probably your PHP config then. Check your `php.ini` file for this line `extension=mysqli` and make sure it does not have a `;` prefix. If it does, remove the `;` and restart PHP.

Comment: already configured it Sir. still showing same error